# pdo_sqlsrv error on SSL certificate verification process

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, sqlsrv

using ubuntu 22, php8.2, odbc driver 18, OpenSSL 3.0.2, when I try to connect with a sqlsrv database using pdo_sqlsrv, it return me this error:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

the code I've used:

```
<?php
$sSGBD = "sqlsrv";
$sDatabase = "db_Des";
$sServer = "10...24";
$sUser = "aplic_...";
$sPwd = "....";


try {
        if(!$oPDO) {
                $oPDO = new PDO ("$sSGBD:Server=$sServer;Database=$sDatabase","$sUser","$sPwd");
                $oPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
              echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

I have a server in production with Debian 11, php 7.3, ODBC 17, openssl 1.1 and pdo_sqlsrv and it connects well with my 2008 sqlsrv database. I've already tried to run the script with another server with the same specs(Debian 11, php 7.3, ODBC 17, openssl 1.1(same configuration)) but it return me the same error I got in ubuntu 22.

in my php 8.2 installation that uses ubuntu 22, I tried to connect with both sqlsrv 2008 and sqlsrv 2022 and it didn't work.

Comment: You could add the `TrustServerCertificate = true` option to the connection URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrustServerCertificate=false  or  TrustServerCertificate=true

you can  try it with pdo dsn parameter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => true,
PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE => true,
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8
```

Comment: try this, didn't work

Comment: How could this solve the SSL issue?

Comment: you can set dsn  :

Comment: set dsn: sqlsrv:Database=F22D;Server=219.133.1.71,1688;TrustServerCertificate=true